# nvarchar in sql ,oracle and mysql in Hibernate annotation mapping

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008, oracle11g, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

We are using MS-SQL ,Oracle and mysql as our database.

We have used hibernate annotations to create tables, in the annotation class file we have declared column definition as

@Column(name="UCAALSNO",nullable=false,columnDefinition="nvarchar(20)")
and this works fine for MS-SQL.

But when it comes to Oracle nvarchar throws an exception as oracle supports only nvarchar2 
and Mysql only supports nchar()(max length=255)

How to create annotation file to support datatype nvarchar for three databases.